# Can't click on Google Maps InfoBox

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, jquery-mobile

Why my InfoBox can't be clicked?

I have created the boxText like following:

```
var boxText = document.createElement("div");
boxText.style.cssText = "width:210px; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; padding:18px; color:#FFFFFF; text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #000000;"
boxText.innerHTML = "<span class='infoBox'>"+selectedDistributorArr[0].title+"</span>";
boxText.id = "boxText";
```

I have also assigned it to my marker's InfoBox:

```
var myBxOptions = {
                 content: boxText,
                 disableAutoPan: false,
                 maxWidth: 0,
                 pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-145, -130),
                 zIndex: null,
                 boxStyle: { 
                  background: "url('images/icons/xhdpi/tooltip.png') no-repeat",
                  width: "271px",
                  height: "80px"
                 },
                 closeBoxURL: "",
                 infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
                 isHidden: false,
                 pane: "floatPane",
                 enableEventPropagation: false
        };
marker.infobox = new InfoBox(myBxOptions);
```

I also assigned to click listener but the alert isn't shown at all!

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(boxText, 'click', function() {
            alert("ALERT!");
});
```

I believe it's the correct way how to do it or do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of quick ideas.

Are you putting the listener on the correct thing? The boxText is just a variable whereas the infobox seems to me what it needs be placed on.

Also, if not that, does the enableEventPropagation being set to false prevent the listener from firing?

Comment: Hi Rafe, sorry just came back to my question again. Yes I put the listener to correct thing since I follow some tutorial out there. I think the enableEventPropagation must be set to false to enable the event listener.